# PDO: Binding data trough an array when selecting

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to set an array containig all required parameters for my PDO queries on a file, and the first of those queries is a `SELECT` making use of just one parameter.

```
$data = array(
            'us_id'   => $_POST['us_id'],
            'us_credits' => $_POST['us_credits'],
            'us_access' => $_POST['us_access']
        );

$selectUsers= "SELECT * FROM ws_users WHERE us_id= :us_id";

$statementSelectUsers = $pdo->prepare($selectUsers);
$statementSelectUsers->execute($data);
$result = $statementSelectUsers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$us_fk_ui_id =  $result['us_fk_ui_id'];
```

On executing, a Fatal Error emerges:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens' in
>   C:\wamp\www\waisap\actions\ad_updateUserInfo.php on line 25

Line 25 is the `$statementSelectUsers->execute($data);` line

As far as I've learned, a `SELECT` query on PDO does not need to `execute()`, but if no query is executed, I can not pass binded data contained on my array to query's placeholders. Is this the reason for the error? How to pass an array to be applied on my `SELECT` query's placeholders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me repeat what I told you in the other answer 5 minutes ago:

> array keys have to match placeholders in the query. If your queries have different sets of placeholders, you will need different arrays as well.

So, that's the reason for this problem.

> As far as I've learned, a SELECT query on PDO does not need to execute(),

You've learned it wrong. You have to execute everything that has been prepared.

First, create `$data` array with only one element and use it for `SELECT`

```
$data = array('us_id'   => $_POST['us_id']);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT us_fk_ui_id FROM ws_users WHERE us_id= :us_id");
$stmt->execute($data);
$us_fk_ui_id = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

for the later queries add other items to this array

Comment: I misunderstood your explanation. It does not only need to have the same placeholders (literally, matching placeholders), it does require the same SETS of placeholders. My mistake, thank you